# Persistant storage AIR for Mobile

Tags: android, ios, mobile, air, storage

I have a Pure AS3 app that I'm deploying to both iOS and Android. There is a small amount of data that I'd like to save to the device but I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

Especially if the application gets updated from the market with a bug fix or new content, in which case I still need to have that data stored.

After digging around, I found this article: http://blog.emobistudio.com/index.php/tag/adobe-air-sdk/  Basically lists the 3 options as SharedObject, SQLLite db, and a file.

- Will any of these three options persist (not get overwritten) after an application update?
- If I go with saving a file, will it be hard to keep the file in the right place on both iOS and Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite or a file will be fine after an update (at least on Android, I don't know anything about iOS, but I'd suspect it should work the same way).

Second question, no, it won't be hard, as long as you don't change your package name and the way you sign your application, the file should end up in the exact same location as before (again, I'm speaking more of Android, I don't know much about iOS).

Comment: Should I be storing it in the File.applicationStorageDirectory ? Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: No, it's not. I just meant that android/embedded linux transparently assigns a private home directory and a userid to an application based on the package name and the signing key. To you, it just means that you don't have to do anything, may be that's what I should have said initially. My convoluted explanation was not being helpful.