# Persistent storage of game scores AIR for Android

Tags: android, air

I need to store a user's game scores.
I saw this posting
'[Persistant storage AIR for Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038691/persistant-storage-air-for-mobile)'

but still not sure what the pros and cons are for the following methods

-storing to a file
-local shared object
-encrypted local store
-sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a local shared object. It's easy to use and your game scores probably won't exceed the size limit. Here are some pros and cons of the different methods:

### File

Pros: No size limit
Cons: You have to create your own file format to store data

### Local Shared Object

Pros: Very easy to use, you can store arbitrary Actionscript objects
Cons: Size limited to 100KB

### EncryptedLocalStore

Pros: Secure storage for sensitive data like user passwords
Cons: Slow, can store only ByteArrays

### SQLite

Pros: SQL database that can be queried efficiently
Cons: You have to have to design a database schema, API is cumbersome